# Java - Return an array that contains a multidimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to solve this for the past couple of hours with no luck, Here I'm supposed to pass in a multidimensional Array from the main method, to another method that's:

```
    public static int[] CalcAllRowSums(int[][] a)
{
    int[] p = {a.length}; 
    int x = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    for ( int r = 0; r < a.length; r++ ) {

        for ( int c = 0; c <= a[x].length-1; c++ ) {
            sum += a[x][r];
        }
        p[x] = sum;
    }
    return p;
}
```

This is how I did it, but when I print out the method from the main method I get the address instead of the actual array.

Thank

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29) to print the string representation of the array.

Sample :

```
System.out.println("Fourth Question " + 
                    Arrays.toString(TwoD.CalcAllRowSums(array)));
```

But why are you returning `int[]` instead of a plain `int` ?

Comment: It didn't work, where Do I need to put .toString() ? Here's my main Method:
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Fourth Question " + TwoD.CalcAllRowSums(array));
    }

Comment: @JackOsborn Wherever you are trying to print your array, if you array is named x. Then use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));`

Comment: Now I'm getting Cannot find Variable Arrays, which is the part I don't actually get

Comment: Have you imported it ? `import java.util.Arrays;` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is not such things as a multidimensional array, there's only array of arrays.
Each row of your main array contains an array (of possible different length)

First, are you sure you want to store the array length in the array : `int[] p = {a.length};` ? 
If you want to create an array of a.length, just write `int[] p = new int[a.length];`.

Second, as The New Idiot said, use [Arrays.toString(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) if you want to have a String reprensentation of your array.

In my example below :
`System.out.print(rowSums)` returns the adresse of the array like `[I@4ad6be89`
`System.out.print(Arrays.toString(rowSums))` returns a string representation like `[1,3,42]`

Here's an example :

```
public static int[] sumEachRows(int[][] array) {
    int[] rowSums = new int[array.length];

    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        rowSums[x] = sumOfArray(array[x]);
    }
      System.out.println(rowSums);
      System.out.println(Array.toString(rowSums));
    return rowSums;
}

public static int sumOfArray(int[] array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int element: array)
        sum += element; 
    return sum;
}
```